# Game developed in iOS5 doesn't look centered when the same game got executed in iPhone 5. But works fine in iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have developed a game which works fine in the iOS5 simulator and and iPhone4s. But the problem exists when the same game got executed in iPhone5. It doesn't look centered it look like http://screencast.com/t/nOYlLtjguuUJ. I heard that the iPhone5 size has been increased to 568 * 320. My game works in landscape mode. can any one help me to sort out this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you've enabled iphone 5 screen sizing (by providing the iPhone 5 specific Default.png) but not updated your code to actually resize your game to fit the new size.

Comment: @Jasarien Thank you very much friend i sorted out this problem. I was rolling my head for the past two days to fix this issue. With your help i have fixed this issue in a minute. I have removed the default568@2x.png. Now every thing is fine. Once again thank you very much for your help .